# using NextAuth hooks useSession() inside getServerSideProps()

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I'm trying to get some data from my server depending on whose currently logged in. I'm using Next-Auth and normally I can just call:

```
const { data: session } = useSession();
```

At the top of the functional component, but you cannot do this in `getServerSideProps()`.

I need to make a get request like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session.id}/following`
  );
  const isFollowing = res.json();
  return {
    props: { props: isFollowing },
  };
}
```

that has the current users session ID dynamically put in.

How do I access my session ID ***inside***  `getServerSideProps`?

Answer (score 3):

Since useSession is react-hook - it can be used only inside Component. For server-side usage there another method from Next-Auth package - getSession.
https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#getsession

**Server-Side Example**

```
    import { getSession } from "next-auth/client"

    export default async (req, res) => {
      const session = await getSession({ req })
      /* ... */  
      res.end()
    }
```

Note: When calling getSession() server side, you need to pass {req} or context object.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

you should to  re-assign the headers from the `getServerSideProps` request to inner fetch, because that fetch has no headers, cookies or tokens

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const headers=ctx.req.headers //where cookies, jwt or anything
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session.id}/following`,
    {headers}
  );
  const isFollowing = res.json();
  return {
    props: { props: isFollowing },
  };
}
```

Comment: Still giving me the same error of session is undefined. Do you mind explaining what re-assigning the headers is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

This method has been renamed to `getServerSession` in `v4` of `NextAuth` - see
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession . Here is some example code of how to import it and use it:

```
//you must import your NextAuth options. Here is an example path
import { authOptions } from '../app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)
    //now you can use session to pass to an api - this is not real
    const mydata = await fetch(`http://localhost/example/${session.id}`);
   
    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { mydata } }
}
```